# What is Eclipse's Ctrl+O shortcut equivalent in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

In eclipse hitting control+O while in a java file causes eclipse to popup a little window where you can type the name of a method to navigate to it quickly.

[image]

**What is the equivalent of CTRL+O in netbeans 8.0. I am using the eclipse Key map in netbeans but nothing shows up when I try ctrl+o.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> which opens the Navigator. In it you can type to find a class, member, or method.

To open the Navigator, you can also use the Window menu. Under Mac OS X, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: ctrl+7 does not seem to do anything on my MAC I also tried CMD + 7

Comment: I would have to try later on my Mac. You could just try the other control keys together with 7.

Comment: could you take a sceen shot of what it looks like on the PC just to make sure I am seeing the right thing.

Comment: I've added a screenshot from Mac OS X.

Comment: I figured out how it works in NetBeans. I was hopping that Netbeans would only display the methods that match the search value typed in the navigator and hide the methods that don't match the way that eclipse does as my screen shot shows.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-7 opens and focuses the navigator. Is that what you want?

Comment: Lets say I open a large file with a lot of methods I want to navigate to method by just typing the method name that is what Ctrl+O allows me to do with eclipse.

Comment: That's what Ctrl-7 does.

Comment: But the navigator is a separate window focus goes to it rather than staying in an editor, with a popup as shown in the screen shot above.

Comment: Focus does indeed goto navigator but it still behaves similar to Eclipse CTRL+O. All you have to do is press CTRL+7 then start typing. Once your method is highlighted press return and your focus will be returned to the editor. It's not exactly like eclipse but close enough.